# What to expect from an HR interview for a postdoc position?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, interview

I had a successful technical round of interview for a PostDoc position offered by an NGO. Now I am told that I will be interviewed by the HR manager for the same.

I was told that I am technically highly suitable for the role. My question is what would the HR team might be interested to know further. Would they want to know more about personality etc.

Could anyone please suggest what to expect in an HR interview for a postdoc position?

Answer (score 1):

If your technical interviews went well, I would bet the HR meeting will focus on a combination of the following:

1. **Verifying that you meet formal job requirements.** They need to make sure they can actually employ you; you are authorized to work in the country (e.g., are a citizen or have/can apply for an appropriate work permit). They may ask you to confirm that you have a PhD, a common requirement for a postdoc position. Depending on how it is funded, there may be more specific requirements, like having a degree in a certain field or conferred within a certain time period. If you will need some sort of background check, they will go over that process too.
2. **Selling you on the job.** If they offer you a job, they want you to take it! They may use this meeting to describe your (potential) position and how you would fit into the organization. There might be a specific discussion of the offer you'd be receiving (e.g., salary, vacation, benefits) or just a more general pitch about how this is a great place to work, etc. Some organizations do this even before the final candidate is actually selected.
3. **Checking for fit/compatibility/etc.** Pretty self-explanatory. The impressions of the people you with whom you would work should carry more weight, but nevertheless....

In any case, I would take it as a promising sign that you've been asked back. Good luck!